# Win32 background colour

Tags: c++, winapi

```
wc.lpszClassName = "MyWndClassName";
WNDCLASS wc2 = wc;
WNDCLASS wc3 = wc;
wc2.hbrBackground = blueBrush;
wc2.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(0,IDC_WAIT);
wc3.hbrBackground = randBrush;
// Step 3: Register the WNDCLASS instance with Windows.
RegisterClass( &wc );
RegisterClass( &wc2);
RegisterClass( &wc3);
```

For some reason I can't change the background colour of two of the windows, I need each to be different colours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please paste your code here, not on some other website. http://stackoverflow.com/ is here to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers; what happens when your code host shuts their doors or expires old posts? This would become (more) useless and of no help to others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: And when you do post it here, post just the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks guys, should have realised that!

Any ideas on a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're registering all three window classes with the same name so you're only ending up with one window class. To keep them separate, you need to give each one a unique name. I've edited the relevant code into the question.

Comment: Do you mean in RegisterClass() ?

Comment: Never mind, you meant each classname had to be different. Thank you for help!

Comment: @RBowen: And now you should accept Jerry's answer.